# How can I disable HTML and CSS features in Firebug?

Tags: firebug

I'm using solely the *Console* and the *Network* panel. And quite frankly, Firefox' built-in HTML inspector is both, faster and less resource-intensive. I also guess analysis of HTML eats up most resources, so I'd really like to disable it in Firebug.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML and CSS panel can't be turned off completely, though they can be hidden via Firebug menu > *Visible Panels* > *HTML*/*CSS*.

[image: Menu options to hide specific panels in Firebug]

The most resource intensive parts in the *HTML* panel are highlighting and expanding changes, which can be turned off by unchecking the [options](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu) *Highlight Changes* and *Expand Changes*.

[image: *HTML* panel options]

More resource hungry than the HTML panel is the *Script* panel in Firebug. So if you don't need it, you should turn it off:

[image: *Enabled* option within *Script* panel options]

Comment: Unfortunatelly turning off Script panel disables also DOM inspector which is definitelly necesary. Any idea why is it impossible to disable (rather than hide) HTML and CSS panels? I knew about the *Hide* option already.

Comment: As I said before, they don't use as much resources as the *Script* panel or the *Net* panel. I guess that's the main reason they can't be disabled. Non-the-less it's a valid use case to allow to disable them. That would be a valid enhancement request. Though [Firebug 3 will be based on the built-in DevTools](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/11/10/firebug-3-next-generation-of-firebug/), so it will probably use much less resources through that step.